# Pass additional args in autoform method in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I insert docs with my quickform

```
{{> quickForm id=id collection=collection type="method" meteormethod="createDoc"}}
```

but I also want to set `userId` on all inserted docs.

I have the variable `userId` in my template, so I wonder if I can just do something like

```
{{> quickForm id=id collection=collection type="method" meteormethod="createDoc" userId=userId}}
```

and use the passed variable in my server method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional params in the autoform hooks:

Html

> ```
> {{> quickForm id="idForm" collection=collection type="method" meteormethod="createDoc"}}
> ```

JS

```
AutoForm.hooks({
        idForm: {
            before: {
                method: function(doc) {
                    doc.user = {}
                    doc.user._id = Meteor.user()._id;
                    doc.user.username = Meteor.user().username;
                    return doc;
                }               
            },
            onSuccess: function(formType, result) {             
                console.log(formType, result);
                this.resetForm();
            },
            onError: function(formType, error) {
                console.log(formType, error)
            }

            }
        }
    });
```

For more details, check this section of the documentation
[Callbacks/Hooks](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks)

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the variable in the template into the hook? I cannot use just `Meteor.user()`.

Comment: In my case i'm add more data in the hook, other option is add the variable in the server side using `this.userId;` .